# WCF RIA Entity With Include Not Materializing in Silverlight Client

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm having an impossible time figuring out why my returned child entities are null for a particular query:

The item has a child property with a 0 or 1 multiplicity called `MetaDataItem`.

```
var res = ObjectContext.Contents.Include("MetaDataItem");
```

This works.  I can confirm that `res` contains 1 instance of MetaDataItem.

On the client:

```
var loadOperation = _cContext.Load(_cContext.GetItemQuery(itemId.Value)....
Content item = _cContext.Contents.First(c => c.ContentId == itemId.Value);
```

Here `item.MetaDataItem` is `null` instead of containing the one instance.

Here is the metadata class (note that I DO have an include attribute):

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Content.ContentMetadata))]
public partial class Content
{
    internal sealed class ContentMetadata
     {
         [Include]
         public MetaDataItem MetaDataItem { get; set; }
     }
}
```

So, why isn't my object populating?  What else should I be looking at?  Unfortunately, this appears to be where the `magic` of RIA services occurs, so I can't even really get a handle on attempting to debug the issue.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You should run Fiddler and inspect the response in the Inspection tab. Look for WCF Silverlight.

Comment: It might be caused with missing/incorrect [AssociationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.associationattribute.aspx). You have to reference a key in parent entity (Content) such as ContentId to make RIA Services correctly relate them on the client.